# doctrine mongodb document does not update fields

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

Working with Symfony 3, added new field to a Document, setters, does not save new field. On Symfony 2 it was solved by clearing cache and restarting server, but now it does not help

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 */
private $creatorName;

 /**
 * Set creatorName
 *
 * @param string $creatorName
 * @return $this
 */
public function setCreatorName($creatorName)
{
    $this->creatorName = $creatorName;
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: solved by restart of computer =/